# Serial to Ethernet converter connected directly to router/switch

Tags: serial-port, ethernet

I have a digital scale for trucks that is currently connected to a Windows XP computer that is unusable because of all the bloatware and viruses installed in it and the fact that the pc is 15 years old and it can't be formatted because the software and drivers for weighing the vehicles would be lost.

I'd like to develop a web application and configure a pc with Ubuntu Server running LAMP, and upgrade the whole thing so I can get rid of the old XP computer and work everything from a web browser.

I can connect and process the serial data using either NodeJs or Python, but I did that by connecting to the scale directly with my laptop.

What I need is to be able to connect to the serial port from another office where the PC with Ubuntu Server will be.

Is it possible to attach the digital scale to an ethernet adapter that doesn't require a host computer ???

My main problem is that I need the server to **not** be in the same room where the scale is and ethernet is my only option since there is an ethernet cable that runs undeground to where the scale is and is connected to a small switch which the people that weigh the trucks use.

I guess one option would be to use a Raspberry Pi maybe (since it's small enough) to connect the to the LAN and to the scale, and transmit the data whenever the server requests it, but I don't know if maybe just by using a converter only, the server could connect to the scale and get the data without the use of a host...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are many standalone serial-to-ethernet adapters with a built-in server of various degrees of sophistication, such as [this](https://www.lantronix.com/products/xdirect/) from lantronix (about 100euro). Though more expensive than a Pi, you need to consider the environment it will be in, w.r.t. electrical noise, vibration, temperature etc. A Pi is not an industrial device.

Comment: got it! thank you for your answer. That is precisely what I need. A stand alone serial to ethernet adapter. I'll take a look and see what I can find. Thanks again for your reply